# How to save , show and delete favourite places in android app using sqlite db?

Tags: android, sqlite

I make  different  DB  and then  insert  values to DB from below  coding.Is this right way ? If  yes can  you tell  how to show stored values?

```
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(turnoffon==0)
            {

            imstar.setImageResource(R.drawable.stars);

                get_fav=trname.getText().toString();
                db.open();
                db.insert(get_fav);
                db.close();
                 Intent is= new Intent(Clicked_Result.this,Favlist.class);
                startActivity(is);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved toFavorits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            turnoffon=1;
            }
```

Comment: refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: If you have any query just ping me

Comment: I suggest you that’s not good way to insert all data in one table.you have to make another table of Favourite places.with foreign key of user id of registration table.

Comment: Is  this  right  way  ? I make  different  database  and  then  save  favourites places from  below  coding  to  the  DB
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(turnoffon==0)
    {
     
    imstar.setImageResource(R.drawable.stars);
                
     get_fav=trname.getText().toString();
db.open();
     db.insert(get_fav);
     db.close();
Intent is= new Intent(Clicked_Result.this,Favlist.class);
     startActivity(is);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationConte

Comment: See  the  edited code  above.

Comment: what kind of data you want to save?

Comment: Want to  save the  text   and then onclick want to retrieve place details